# Why 'publish' website produces bin with one dll and build script produces bin with lots of dlls

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

I have made a script that uses the following command...

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
>   "C:\Repositories\Software\trunk\main\upload\UploadWebsite.csproj"
>   /p:Configuration=Release

This makes a website pre-compiled the bin directory has lots of dlls in it and tons of .compiled files...

However when I 'right click' on the project in visual studio I am able to 'publish' the website to a folder and this creates a pre-compiled website with only one dll. This is the preferable option im just wondering what the difference between the two is....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that for a Website project, the publish feature of Visual Studio compiles everything into one dll, while the normal build operation compiles every page into a seperate DLL.
Maybe these articles can help:

[Publishing Web Application with MsBuild](http://blog.m.jedynak.pl/2008/03/publishing-web-application-with-msbuild.html)

[How to publish a web site with MSBuild](http://codingcockerel.co.uk/2008/05/18/how-to-publish-a-web-site-with-msbuild/)

Comment: yeah but why? How do I get the MSbuild to do the same as visual studio?

Comment: The articles I linked show how to automate the publishing process with MSBuild, I thought that's exactly what you were looking for?